# Authorization interception in Apache Shiro with Spring Boot integration does not work

Tags: spring-boot, shiro

Authorization interception in Apache Shiro with Spring Boot integration does not work

```java
  @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principalCollection) {
        User user = (User) SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipal();
        logger.info(user.getUsername()+"----------------------------"+user.getRoles());
        if (user != null) {
            SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
            info.addStringPermission(user.getPerms());
            return info;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

this is controller

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping({"","/login"})
    public String loginPage(){
        return "admin/login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password) throws Exception {
        Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username,password);
        try {
            subject.login(token);
            return "admin/index";
        } catch (IncorrectCredentialsException ice) {
            throw new MyException(ResultCode.INCORRECTCREDENTAILERROR);
        } catch (UnknownAccountException uae) {
            throw new MyException(ResultCode.UNKONWNACCOUNTERROR);
        } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
            throw new MyException(ResultCode.USERNAMEPASSWORDERROR);
        }
    }
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String adminIndex(){
        return "admin/index";
    }
}
```

here is interception, where `"/admin/**"`, `"perms[admin:manage]"` doesn't work, but replace it with `"/admin/index"`, `"perms[admin:manage]"` and it working.

```java
@Bean(name = "shiroFilter")
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter(@Qualifier("securityManager") DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager){
        ShiroFilterFactoryBean bean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
        bean.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
        bean.setLoginUrl("/admin/login");
        bean.setUnauthorizedUrl("/");
        Map<String,String> filterChainDefinitionMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/css/**", "anon");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/images/**", "anon");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/js/**", "anon");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/lib/**", "anon");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/", "anon");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/admin", "anon");

        //problem here
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/admin/**", "perms[admin:manage]");

        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/admin/**", "authc");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/**", "anon");
        bean.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionMap);
        return bean;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the artifact `<artifactId>shiro-spring-boot-web-starter`, not `shiro-spring`.